# ansible "when statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters"

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x

I have read a number of examples of how to re-write the `when` clause to avoid the warning about jinja2 template delimiters `{{` and `}}` - but have not seen any on avoid use of `{% for ... %}`.

I have roughly the following step:

```
- name: Wait for Started status to clear
  uri:
    url: http://{{ container.ip }}:8080/upgrade/api/v1/upgrades/{{ theuuid }}
    return_content: yes
  register: progress_status
  until: >
    {% for c in (progress_status.content | from_json).data.states %}
      {{ c.state != 'Started' }}
      {% if not loop.last %}and{% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  retries: 30
  delay: 15
```

The `uri` call returns a list of containers and their 'state' in a json form.  I want to keep querying this `uri` until none of the containers are in the `Started` state.

This generates the warning due to the `{% for ... %}` loop.

I could do a less specific test by look at the entire response for the json string representing a state of Started.  But that seems more cryptic than looking at the state of each container (building up a boolean expression of `true and true and ...`).  But this is my alternative for now.

Or I could use a `block` and do the query, and then build the condition as a fact, and then use the fact as the `until` on the block.  But that too seems harder to read.

Suggestions for how to handle this sort of pattern?

Comment: I would rather create a shell script in previous task (as a template) that does what the loop in your `until` statement does and which would return zero when every container is stopped. Then you can run that script as `local_action`
Then your `until` statement would only need to check for the result of the script and your playbook would look a lot easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `selectattr`/`rejectattr` filters to fetch/delete specific items from lists:

```
until: (progress_status.content | from_json).data.states | rejectattr('state','equalto','Started') | list | length == 0
```

Here we take `(progress_status.content | from_json).data.states` list, remove all elements that have `state=='Started'` and check length of remaining list.

Task will complete when the list after reject is empty meaning all items have `Started` state.

Comment: Excellent solution!  Thanks - it works great and is the sort of elegance I was looking for!